# Can I uninstall my apps or packages on Ubuntu 20.04 perfectly?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, software-installation, storage

I installed many apps through Terminal. I notice that my storage had 120GB left and I installed 1 GB app then I uninstalled it and I got 119.5GB left. Where is my 500MB??? so my storage keeps decreasing day by day

I've tried apt-get purge  to remove compeletely but my storage's still the same

I've been using Ubuntu for 2 days so please help

Comment: You also made sure the recycle bin was empty?

Comment: Yes, I did it everytime I use my computer

Comment: Disk space isn't only used by the applications you installed. There's also files in many other places such as log files in `/var/log`. I wouldn't be too worried about it as this is perfectly normal. You can use tools like `baobab` and `ncdu` to learn where the disk space went, but don't be tempted to go round randomly deleting things. Many new users do this and break their systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found out that I can use `BleachBit` to clean my system

Comment: When you install a package, it may have dependencies that also need to be installed in order for it to be run, so until your package system is *cleaned* those now orphaned packages will remain.  If you want to hurry the process, you can issue the `apt autoremove` command to start the process yourself.

Comment: Use of `BleachBit` is not necessary on an Ubuntu system. Properly uninstalled software should leave nothing behind (a couple exceptions). If you discover software from the Ubuntu repositories that improperly leaves files behind, report the bug.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you installed these programs.

If you have used APT, just run it:

```
sudo apt autoremove [package_name] [package_name] [package_name] [package_name] [package_name] [package_name] [package_name] [package_name]
```

Of course you can specify multiple packages separated by a blank space.

If you used Snap, you have to run:

```
sudo snap remove [program]
```

Finally, you should do a system optimisation with Stacer to remove a lot of unnecessary packages and files that take up space.

You can consult these posts as a guide, [this](https://www.imaginelinux.com/uninstall-programs-from-ubuntu-system/) one for uninstalling programs and [this](https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-stacer-on-ubuntu/) one for using Stacer.